# Is it possible to add id to a label tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have:

```
<label for="gender" class="error">Choose</label>
```

I would like to add an id to this line via jQuery/javascript so the html would end up like:

```
<label for="gender" class="error" id="addthisid">Choose</label>
```

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("label[for='gender']").attr("id", "addthisid");
```

or:

```
$("label[for='gender']")[0].id = "addthisid";
```

or:

```
$("label[for='gender']").get(0).id = "addthisid";
```

Comment: in jquery higher than 1.6, shouldn't you use prop("id", "addthisid") ?

Comment: No, `.prop` is for retrieving property values, whereas `.attr` is for retrieving attributes. Sounds a bit confusing, but it's explained here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to do that with jQuery. So here we go.

```
$(function(){
    $('label').attr('id', 'addthisid');
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/RkCLR/